# Atmega16 [expected ; before numeric constant] when using output names with numbers

Tags: c, atmega

I am trying to use a Atmega16 IC to open its output pin PORTC1 to blink a led for 500ms. Using the following code in AtmelStudio7 gives an error "expected ; before numeric constant", when I click the error, it points me to the space between number 1 and "PORTC.". I guess, the compiler does not understand, that I want to "point to pin C number 1" and thinks that "1" goes somewhere else. Please, point me in the right direction. The code that does not work and show the error:

```
#define  F_CPU  8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRC.1 |= 1>>0;
    PORTC.1 &= ~(1>>0);
    while (1) 
    {
    PORTC.1 |= (1>>0);
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTC.1 &= ~(1>>0);
    _delay_ms(500); 
    }
}
```

But, when I am using pin 0 (just DDRC, PORT without adding numbers), it works fine. Example of working code:

```
#define  F_CPU  8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void)
{
    DDRC |= 1>>0;
    PORTC &= ~(1>>0);
    while (1) 
    {
    PORTC |= (1>>0);
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTC &= ~(1>>0);
    _delay_ms(500); 
    }
}
```

The difference here is that "DDRC" and "PORTC" work, but using "DDRC.1" and "PORTC.1" do not, showing the following error "expected ; before numeric constant".
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It means `PORTC` is a macro whose value is equated to the register address of `PORTC` of microcontroller and this also means that `PORTC` is not a structure or union containing bit fields for PORTC of uC.

Comment: Instead of `DDRC.n |= 1>>0` you have to use `DDRC |= 1<<n` etc. pp. (note, that the `>>` go the wrong way in your examples, too)

Comment: that helped. thank you!  so the correct way to do this is
DDRC |= 1<<n , where "n" is the port number on the IC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set specific GPIO pins to output, you should used this approach:

```
DDRD |= 1 << pin_number;
DDRD |= 1 << 1; //Shift 1 for 1 bit = PD1 pin set to output.
```

The same approach goes for all registers.

To clear bits:

```
DDRD &= ~(1 << pin_number);
DDRD &= ~(1 << 1); //Set PD1 to input
```

`PORTC.1` is not valid C statement and that's why you have an error.